# Android: Making a Looping HorizontalScrollView of a Panoramic Image with Javascript

Tags: javascript, android, image, loops, panoramas

I want to make a panoramic image scrollable, and to loop back and 'stitch' its front to its back after the user has reached the end of the image.

The effect I'm trying to recreate is congruent to the one found in [Trying to create an infinite horizontal scroll - preferably using a jquery plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6398074/trying-to-create-an-infinite-horizontal-scroll-preferably-using-a-jquery-plugin).

The only problem is that I need it to be in Javascript, because I'm doing it on the Android.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here's what worked for me. Append the same image behind the first one, that way when you get to the end of the first one, it will look like a panorama. Then, you could check scrollLeft() and adjust the position based on which way the user is scrolling.